# How can I enable GitHub preview features, like topics?

Tags: github-api, octokit.net, probot

I'm using [Apps - listRepos](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#api-Apps-listRepos) to get a list of all the repositories installed on my Probot GitHub application.

I want the response data to include the GitHub **topics** for each repository. This is currently only [available as a preview feature](https://developer.github.com/v3/apps/installations/):

> The topics property for repositories on GitHub is currently available for developers to preview. To view the topics property in calls that return repository results, you must provide a custom media type in the Accept header:
>
> `application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json`

So I think I want to "provide a custom media type in the Accept header".

Is there a way to enable GitHub preview features in Probot? Perhaps by somehow setting [RequestOptions](https://github.com/probot/probot/blob/master/src/github/index.ts#L31)?

Comment: Update: This issue might be related: https://github.com/probot/probot/issues/760

Comment: Update 2: Ah, yeah. https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/pull/1083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success: I added a `headers` object to my `listRepos()` call.

```js
const repositories = await octokit.paginate(
  octokit.apps.listRepos({
    per_page: 100,
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json,application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json'
    }
  }),
  res => res.data.repositories // Pull out only the list of repositories from each response.
);
```